# NodeJS TypeError Callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, callback, typeerror

I have the following piece of code:

```
function fun1(callback){
  var result =  "result of function 1";
  callback(result)
};
function fun2(callback){
  var result =  "result of function 2";
  callback(result)
};

fun1(log); // displays "result of function 1"
fun2(log); // displays "result of function 2"
fun2(fun1(log)); // Type Error ...
```

Where log is simple function (i.e. console.log(data)...)
I'm wondering why fun2(fun1(log)) does not display "result of function 1" as one would expect. What is missing? Many thanks - Christian

Answer (score 2):

fun2 expects to get a function.
what you gave is the result (which is 'undefined') of func1.
meaning

```
var something = fun1(log);
fun2(something);
```

So not sure what you expect to do in fun2 but you need to provide a callback and not undefined.

you could do:

```
function fun1(callback){
  var result =  "result of function 1";
  callback(result)
  return callback
};
function fun2(callback){
  var result =  "result of function 2";
  callback(result)
};

fun1(log); // displays "result of function 1"
fun2(log); // displays "result of function 2"
fun2(fun1(log));
```

Comment: Thanks Sagie for your quick response. Is this the standard way of doing when you want to chain functions together?

Comment: there are many ways to chain functions, for example to return a function, to use promise and so on... there is no 1 specific standard way.